# Nginx php-fpm high cpu usage

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm

I have a problem with a high traffic wordpress, super high CPU load under nginx php-fpm, I am caching with apc, and memcached, spent 2-3 days tweaking configs and looking for answers it seems to me that php-fpm takes up all the cpu available no matter how many max_children i set if i set 5 then the load is 20% each, if i set 20 then the load adds up till 90% i tried static and dynamic

server is 2x3.0Ghz 6GB Ram SSD in raid 10 on ubuntu 12.04 x64

utpime:
17:27:51 up  2:19,  1 user,  load average: 29.79, 28.08, 26.29
what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP takes what it can get. You say that you have a lot of traffic. Even if you use the caching, PHP still does some checking and calculating and stuff. This adds up.

The more important thing is: Does it feel/is it slow?

Comment: it doesn't, i just thought that it's something wrong cause people talk about how the load should be ~ 1, I guess I am being paranoid :)